# Need some guidance moving an SVN repository to another solution

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Currently our SVN runs on a local server here in the office. That server is being retired and management doesn't want to replace it since SVN is the only purposes it serves (really old server). So we are looking at a cloud solution like Unfuddle (they seem to be very highly rated in google searches).

So I have a couple of questions:

1. If we don't care about previous commits and only want to current state of the repo (code base is mature and solid), would we just "add" to the new account? If so, what svn command line would you recommend?
2. Should this be done from a workstation with a current copy from the repo or directly from the server to the new location using the "init" and "sync" command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, "just add" to the new repo at the new location. I'll recommend understanding of operation, not just monkey-job. You have: create new empty repository, checkout it's trunk (get empty local WC), unversion old WC (remove .svn dir), copy this unversioned tree into the root of *new WC*,  add all intoSubversion, commit
2. Yes, it have to be done from workstation with WC, updated to HEAD of old repo

Comment: What is WC mean, "Working Copy"?

Comment: I did what you stated and it worked like a charm but I don't see the branch, tag, and trunk folders like we had under our old repo. Can you offer any tips here? Even if you can't, I'm still marking this as the correct answer.

Comment: I found in the manual/on line pdf book how to setup the folders.

Comment: @DLackey - they are ordinary folders, you can create it with `svn mkdir URL` on server (or checkout into new temp location full repo from root, create needed folders locally and commit)